# SSL and Forms Based Authentication in WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, security, ssl, forms-authentication

I have a FBA application and we would like to use SSL with it.

By default, does setting SSL in IIS use SSL for the entire site, or just the login?

We think we'd like to use SSL for the entire visit to the site.  Is there any way to configure it to do so, if this isn't the default setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your site in IIS, when you apply your SSL certificate to it, this applies to the entire site. Please read the instructions here: http://www.harbar.net/articles/ssl.aspx especially if you are using SSL for multiple sites. I found this to be invaluable when setting up SSL the first time with SharePoint.